# Difference between "having" and "having had"

Tags: verbs

Often, I've seen 'having' with verb 3form but it doesn't make sense to me at all

> **Having** done work, I went home",

Does this mean "I did work first with myself then I went home"?  or anything else?

> **Having had** the work done, I went home?

Does it mean here, "First I got work done with other people, then I went home"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re your question "with myself" i.e. alone.

**Having completed the task, I was able to leave.** = *Because I had finished the task, I was free to go.*

Such a locution implies that "I" had done the task alone.  If you wanted to involve others, it would be:

**Because we had completed the task, I was free to go.**  or **Because we had completed the task, we were free to go.**

There is no way to express that idea *in the initial clause* when it begins "Having completed" because there is no way of expressing differences in **number** with "having completed".  The number will be in the second, independent clause:

```
Having completed the task, I was free to go.
Having completed the task, he was free to go.
Having completed the task, they were free to go.
```

Prosecuting attorney:

**Colonel Mustard, having completed the task, did you leave the premises immediately? Or did you stick around and murder Professor Plum in the living room with the candelabra?**

HAVING HAD...

**I had a scar on my belly, having had my appendix removed as a child.**

You cannot remove your own appendix. So you *had it removed*. That is, you took action to have another person remove it.

**I will have the house painted before we put it up for sale.**

means that you will hire someone to paint the house for you.

**After having had the house painted, we put it up for sale but then decided to stay.**
**After having the house painted, we put it up for sale.**

Comment: What about: "I feel better after having had some sushi"

Comment: *had* = "eaten" there.   What will you have when we go out to dinner?  I'll have some sushi.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. But this construction is not common in spoken English. It's a bit formal.
Here are my examples:

1. Having got my degree, I started looking for a job. (I started looking for a job after getting my degree.)
2. Having had my hair cut, I took a bath. (I had my hair cut and then took a bath.)